# Multi-input model with generator function - Keras R

Tags: r, image-processing, keras, regression

I have been trying to build a multi-input model in keras. One input branch would be  images and the second one some metaData for the corresponding images.

For the images I need a generator function which would input batches of images. The metaData is in a tabular form.

Now I am wondering how I should pass the data to the model so the right image would  be processed with the respective metaData Information. For your Information this will be a regression Task.

The Input Data I have:

- Images in dir1/
- Data Frame with the path and features.

  ```
  path       feature1 feature2 target
  image1.jpg 23.5     100      16
  image2.jpg 25.0     88       33
  ```

The code I have for now:

- generator function for Images:

  ```
  train_datagen <- image_data_generator(rescale = 1/255)

  train_generator <- flow_images_from_dataframe(
    dataframe = joined_path_with_metadata,
    directory = 'data_dir',
    x_col = "path",
    y_col = "train",
    generator = train_datagen,
    target_size = c(150, 150),
    batch_size = 20,
    color_mode = 'rgb',
    class_mode = "sparse"
  )
  ```
- model definition:

  ```
  vision_model <- keras_model_sequential() 

  vision_model %>% 
    layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, 
                  kernel_size = c(3, 3), 
                  activation = 'relu', 
                  padding = 'same',
                  input_shape = c(150, 150, 3)) %>% 
    layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2, 2)) %>% 
    layer_flatten()

  # Now let's get a tensor with the output of our vision model:
  image_input <- layer_input(shape = c(150, 150, 3))
  encoded_image <- image_input %>% vision_model

  # ANN for tabular data

  tabular_input <- layer_input(shape = ncol(dataframe), dtype = 'float32')

  mlp_model <- tabular_input %>% 
    layer_dense(
      units              = 16, 
      kernel_initializer = "uniform", 
      activation         = "relu") # Dropout to prevent overfitting
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.1) %>%
    layer_dense(
      units              = 32, 
      kernel_initializer = "uniform", 
      activation         = "relu") %>% 

  # concatenate the metadata and the image vector then
  # train a linear regression on it
  output <- layer_concatenate(c(mlp_model, encoded_image)) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation='linear')


  # This is the final model:
  vqa_model <- keras_model(inputs = c(image_input, tabular_input), outputs = output)
  ```
- compile:

  ```
  vqa_model %>% compile(
    optimizer = 'adam',
    loss      = 'mean_squared_error',
    metrics   = c('mean_squared_error')
  )
  ```

and the last step would be to fit the model. I am not sure how to do this to make sure that the first row of features will be taken as the metadata of the Images which are read in in batches.